# Entity Framework 6 Update Graph

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-server-ce-4

What is the correct way to save a graph of objects whose state you don't know? By state I mean whether they are new or existing database entries that are being updated.

For instance, if I have:

```
public class Person
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Automobile> Automobiles { get; set; }

}

public class Automobile
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Name { get; set; }
     public short Seats { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<MaintenanceRecord> MaintenanceRecords { get; set ;}
     public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class MaintenanceRecord
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int AutomobileId { get; set; }
     public DateTime DatePerformed { get; set; }

     public virtual Automobile Automobile{ get; set; }

}
```

I'm editing models, similar to these objects above, and then passing those models into the data layer to save, where for this instance I happen to be using entity framework. So I'm translating these models into POCO entities internal to the DAL.

It appears that unless my models have a state indicating whether they are new or updated, I have quite a bit of work to do to "Save" the changes. I have to first select the Person entity, update it, then match any existing Automobiles and update those and add any new, then for each automobile check for any new or updated maintenance records.

Is there a faster/easier way of doing this? It's possible I can keep track of the Model state, which I guess would be helpful with this, but it would mean changes to code outside of the data layer which i would prefer to avoid. I'm just hoping there is a pattern of usage out there that I can follow for updates like this.

Comment: BTW, I'm not actually saving information about People and Cars. It was an example of an object with related data.

Comment: Consider to use [EF-Core-Simple-Graph-Update](https://github.com/WahidBitar/EF-Core-Simple-Graph-Update)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add/update child entities when updating a parent entity in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this issue a while back and have been following this thread on the EF Codeplex site. https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864

Seems like it is being considered for the next release, I'm assuming EF 7, which apparently is a pretty large internal overhaul of EF.  This may be worth checking out... http://www.nuget.org/packages/RefactorThis.GraphDiff/

Back when I was working on this I found another EF post on SO, and someone had an example of how to do this manually.  At the time I decided to do it manually, not sure why, GraphDiff looks pretty cool.  Here is an example of what I did.

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutAsync([FromBody] WellEntityModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var kne = TheContext.Companies.First();
            var entity = TheModelFactory.Create(model);
            entity.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;

            var currentWell = TheContext.Wells.Find(model.Id);

            // Update scalar/complex properties of parent
            TheContext.Entry(currentWell).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

            //We don't pass back the company so need to attached the associated company... this is done after mapping the values to ensure its not null.
            currentWell.Company = kne;

            // Updated geometry - ARGHHH NOOOOOO check on this once in a while for a fix from EF-Team https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864
            var geometryItemsInDb = currentWell.Geometries.ToList();
            foreach (var geometryInDb in geometryItemsInDb)
            {
                // Is the geometry item still there?
                var geometry = entity.Geometries.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == geometryInDb.Id);
                if (geometry != null)
                    // Yes: Update scalar/complex properties of child
                    TheContext.Entry(geometryInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(geometry);
                else
                    // No: Delete it
                    TheContext.WellGeometryItems.Remove(geometryInDb);
            }
            foreach (var geometry in entity.Geometries)
            {
                // Is the child NOT in DB?
                if (geometryItemsInDb.All(i => i.Id != geometry.Id))
                    // Yes: Add it as a new child
                    currentWell.Geometries.Add(geometry);
            }

            // Update Surveys
            var surveyPointsInDb = currentWell.SurveyPoints.ToList();
            foreach (var surveyInDb in surveyPointsInDb)
            {
                // Is the geometry item still there?
                var survey = entity.SurveyPoints.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == surveyInDb.Id);
                if (survey != null)
                    // Yes: Update scalar/complex properties of child
                    TheContext.Entry(surveyInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(survey);
                else
                    // No: Delete it
                    TheContext.WellSurveyPoints.Remove(surveyInDb);
            }
            foreach (var survey in entity.SurveyPoints)
            {
                // Is the child NOT in DB?
                if (surveyPointsInDb.All(i => i.Id != survey.Id))
                    // Yes: Add it as a new child
                    currentWell.SurveyPoints.Add(survey);
            }

            // Update Temperatures - THIS IS A HUGE PAIN = HOPE EF is updated to handle updating disconnected graphs.
            var temperaturesInDb = currentWell.Temperatures.ToList();
            foreach (var tempInDb in temperaturesInDb)
            {
                // Is the geometry item still there?
                var temperature = entity.Temperatures.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == tempInDb.Id);
                if (temperature != null)
                    // Yes: Update scalar/complex properties of child
                    TheContext.Entry(tempInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(temperature);
                else
                    // No: Delete it
                    TheContext.WellTemperaturePoints.Remove(tempInDb);
            }
            foreach (var temps in entity.Temperatures)
            {
                // Is the child NOT in DB?
                if (surveyPointsInDb.All(i => i.Id != temps.Id))
                    // Yes: Add it as a new child
                    currentWell.Temperatures.Add(temps);
            }
            await TheContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return InternalServerError();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a huge pain to me too. I extracted the answer from @GetFuzzy to a more reusable method:

```
public void UpdateCollection<TCollection, TKey>(
    DbContext context, IList<TCollection> databaseCollection, 
    IList<TCollection> detachedCollection, 
    Func<TCollection, TKey> keySelector) where TCollection: class where TKey: IEquatable<TKey>
{
    var databaseCollectionClone = databaseCollection.ToArray();
    foreach (var databaseItem in databaseCollectionClone)
    {
        var detachedItem = detachedCollection.SingleOrDefault(item => keySelector(item).Equals(keySelector(databaseItem)));
        if (detachedItem != null)
        {
            context.Entry(databaseItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(detachedItem);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Set<TCollection>().Remove(databaseItem);
        }
    }

    foreach (var detachedItem in detachedCollection)
    {
        if (databaseCollectionClone.All(item => keySelector(item).Equals(keySelector(detachedItem)) == false))
        {
            databaseCollection.Add(detachedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

With this method in place I can use it like this:

```
public void UpdateProduct(Product product)
{
   ...

   var databaseProduct = productRepository.GetById(product.Id);

   UpdateCollection(context, databaseProduct.Accessories, product.Accessories, productAccessory => productAcccessory.ProductAccessoryId);
   UpdateCollection(context, databaseProduct.Categories, product.Categories, productCategory => productCategory.ProductCategoryId);

   ...

   context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

However when the graph gets deeper, I have a feeling this will not be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

What your looking for is the Unit of Work pattern:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx

You can either track UoW on the client and pass it in with the DTO or have the server figure it out. Both the veritable DataSet and EF Entities have their own internal implementation of UoW. For something stand alone there is this framework, but I have never used it so have no feedback:

http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

Alternatively another option is to do real time updates with undo functionality, kind of like when you go into Gmail contacts and it saves the changes as you make them with the option to undo.

Answer (score 0):

It depends **HOW** you are accomplishing adding/changing the entities.

I think you may be trying to do too much with an entity at any given time. Allowing editing and adding at the same time can get you into a situation where your not sure what is being done with the entity, especially in a disconnected scenario. You should only perform a single action on a single entity at a time, unless you are deleting entities.  Does this seem monotonous, sure, but 99% of your users want a clean and easily understandable interface.  Many time we end up making screens of our applications "god" screens where everything and anything can be done.  Which 9/10 times isn't needed (YAGNI).

This way, when you edit a user, you know you are doing an update operation.  If you are adding a new maintenance record, you know you are creating a new record that is attached to an automobile.

To summarize, you should limit how many operations you are making available for a single screen and make sure you provide some type of unique information for the entity so you can try to look up the entity to see if it exists.

Comment: I can look up the entity to see if it exists. That's not my problem. And your assumption that I'm doing something crazy and allowing the user to do "too much" is not accurate. It sounds like you're implying that I should do a single update to a single object at a time as soon as the user makes a change, which is not a workable solution in this scenario. It doesn't seem that odd to me to be working with a disconnected set of entities, let the user add new related entities or change existing ones, then save those changes at once after the user confirms these changes.

Comment: In your third paragraph, 2nd sentence, you state you would have to get the `Person` object and then go through updating the graphs.  Why would you need to do this unless your screen gives many options for updating and adding multiple connected entities?  Normally, a screen has a expected use.  A screen to add or remove Maintenance records, in which case you know you are updating these entities.  A screen to add a new maintenance record, you know you are adding the entity to an automobile, which knows who it belongs to.  In doing it this way, you are "tracking" the entity state.

Comment: You're still making lots of assumptions. But, it's not relevant. The application exists, it's approved, it's being used by customers who do not find it needlessly complicated. I'm only adding a new option for storage by adding another implementation of a Data Access Layer. Your advice to completely rearrange how my application interacts with objects is not helpful. Keeping track of state isn't even the real problem. The issue is updating the entire graph atomically even if I know the state that's the issue. EF doesn't provide much help here, @GetFuzzy's answer implies maybe next release.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, and couldnt find my own solution. I think that problem is complex. Complete solution for updating graphs in disconected scenario with EF6 I find in extension method RefactoringThis.GraphDiff produced by Brent McKendric.

Exemple brings by author is:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())  
{
    // Update the company and state that the company 'owns' the collection Contacts.
    context.UpdateGraph(company, map => map
        .OwnedCollection(p => p.Contacts, with => with
            .AssociatedCollection(p => p.AdvertisementOptions))
        .OwnedCollection(p => p.Addresses)
    );

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

See more at:
http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/